# Creating partly filled disks based on percentage

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to create a function that returns a partly filled `Disk`, based on a percentage. So inputting `1` would give a fully filled disk, while inputting `0.5` would return a `Disk` with half of if it filled (from 12 'o clock to 6 'o clock). Etc.

So far I've written this:

```
Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
          {Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {4 Pi/3, Pi/2}]}}]
```

[image]

The function part is not difficult but I can't get the coordinates to work properly. How do I transform a percentage like 0.1 to the correct segment of the `Disk`? (The `{4 Pi/3, Pi/2}` of the function).

Comment: @Öskå Yes technically a math issue.  `2 Pi * percen`.  Honestly I would just use degree in this case.

Comment: You need `Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, Pi/2 +/- n 2 Pi}]` but I agree with @Öskå.

Comment: ah, I just found it too :) And removed my comment about it.., meh, no awake yet. But [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/582/1356) answer is probably helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion using `Rescale` is not really necessary here. If you want to change both, the percentage `p` and the starting point `s` of the *cake* the formula for the angle argument of `Disk` is simply

```
2Pi*({0, p} + s)
```

This gives

> [image]

and the code is simply

```
percentGauge[p_, start_] := 
 Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, {Blue, 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, 2 Pi ({0, p} + start)]}}]
```

Comment: I'm shocked that `{0, p} + start` appeared in 5th answer... Finally something without redundant parts :)

Answer (score 8):

`Rescale` is useful:

```
percentFill[
   n_] := {90 Degree, (90 +  Rescale[n, {0, 1},  {0, 360}]) Degree};
Table[Graphics[{{
    EdgeForm[Thick], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]},
   {Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, percentFill[p]]}}], {p, 0, 1, .1}]
```

[image: disks]

Answer (score 7):

`"Partly filled disks based on percentage" == PieChart` gives `True` so

```
f[s_] := PieChart[{1 - s, s}, SectorOrigin -> π/2]
```

is what you are looking for.

Usage:

```
f[.2]
```

[image: pie]

**---EDIT---**

`SectorOrigin` set to $  \pi/2 $ to match your requirement for `.5` splitting the disk top-bottom rather than left-right (and also to get @Kuba's +1!)

Comment: Add `SectorOrigin` so it fits OP's needs and you have my +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are on v9, here's another approach (it's different from what you ask, but maybe somebody else will like that):

```
myGauge[x_] := 
   AngularGauge[100 x, {0, 100}, 
      ScaleOrigin -> Reverse@{5 \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
      ScaleOrigin -> Top, 
      ScaleDivisions -> 10, 
      GaugeMarkers -> Placed[Automatic, "ScaleRange"], 
      GaugeLabels -> Placed["Value", Center]]
```

As you can see, I use [`AngularGauge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AngularGauge.html) to solve the issue. I specified some formatting - see the Documentation Center for more options / features (e.g. remove the [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reverse.html) to get other orientation).

Interactively:

```
Manipulate[myGauge[x], {{x, 0.42, "Fraction"}, 0, 1}]
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Degree` to have the circle go around part of the whole.

```
filledDisk[frac_] := Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
  {Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {90 Degree, (90 + frac 360) Degree}]}}]
```

And if you need percentage you can calculate it like so.

```
.1 * 360
```

Comment: Look at the example. It fills from the top... zero degrees is to the right.

Comment: @Anon Well then 90 Degree then

Comment: For a full answer I was looking for something like this: `filledDisk[frac_] := 
 Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, {Blue, 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {90 Degree, (90 + frac 360) Degree}]}}]` and the corresponding function with radians.

Comment: @Anon I amended my answer assuming you don't mind that I use your code.

Comment: @Liam I've never seen a clock turning in that way ;-)

Comment: @Öskå He's using clock coordinates to explain, he's not  trying to create a clock. In his example, the coordinates are given to turn in that direction.